# Pinescript to avoid immediate long/short entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am quite new to pine script coding and seeking some advice on the buy/sell alerts.
When I tried to run the RSI strategy and back test it, I see that the long is immediately followed by a short entry and a short entry is immediately followed by a long entry which makes the script to always stay in a long or a short trade.

For an example, using RSI strategy, the script follows short immediately after long and vice versa as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I would like to change it to make a long entry when a bullish pattern is observed and exit when a stop loss or a criteria is met. Inversely, enter a short trade when a bearish pattern is observed and exit when a stop loss or a criteria is met.

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

I tried long and short strategy and expected it to trade only for certain conditions but not one followed by the other immediately.

Here  is the code of the RSI strategy:

```
//@version=5 
strategy("RSI and Moving Average with Pyramiding", overlay=true) 
// RSI settings 
rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length") 
rsiOverbought = input(70 , title="RSI Overbought Level") 
rsiOversold = input(33, title="RSI Oversold Level") 
// Moving Average settings 
maLength = input(90, title="MA Length") 
maSource = close 
// Pyramiding settings 
maxPositions = input(1, title="Max Positions") 
// Calculate RSI 
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength) 
//plot(rsiValue) 
// Calculate Moving Average 
maValue = ta.sma(maSource, maLength) 
// Entry conditions 
enterLong = ta.crossover(rsiValue, rsiOverbought ) 
enterShort = ta.crossunder(rsiValue, rsiOversold) 
// Exit conditions 
exitLong = ta.crossunder(rsiValue, rsiOverbought) 
exitShort = ta.crossover(rsiValue, rsiOversold) 
// Pyramiding logic 
var bool longConditionMet = false 
var bool shortConditionMet = false 
if enterLong 
    longConditionMet := true 
else if exitLong 
    longConditionMet := false 
    
if enterShort 
    shortConditionMet := true 
else if exitShort 
    shortConditionMet := false 
    
// Execute trades 
if longConditionMet 
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, qty = maxPositions) 
    
if shortConditionMet 
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, qty = maxPositions) 
    
// Plotting 
plot(rsiValue, title="RSI", color=color.rgb(89, 243, 33)) 
plot(close, title="RSI", color=color.rgb(243, 33, 215)) 
plot(maValue, title="Moving Average", color=color.red)
```

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

check for `position_size` before entry and use `strategy.exit()` function

```
// Execute trades 
if longConditionMet and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, qty = maxPositions) 
    strategy.exit("EXIT BUY", "Buy", stop =  close * 1.1)
if shortConditionMet  and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, qty = maxPositions) 
    strategy.exit("EXIT SELL", "Sell", stop =  close * 0.9)
```